# Is this PHP comparison the same?

Tags: php

I basically have this PHP code:

```
<?php 
   $num_1 = $_POST['num_1'];

   if( $num_1 == 1 || $num_1 == 2 ){
       // Do something
   }
?>
```

What I know is that `$num_1` can either be `1` or `2`. This is the value I expect from `$_POST['num_1']`

What I want to know is that instead of using `if( $num_1 == 1 || $num_1 == 2 )` could I use or is that the same to use:

```
<?php 
   $num_1 = $_POST['num_1'];

   if( $num_1 == ( 1 || 2 ) ){
       // Do something
   }
?>
```

The difference here is that previously I was using `if( $num_1 == 1 || $num_1 == 2 ){}` but now I am using `if( $num_1 == ( 1 || 2 ) ){}`

I am trying to wrap my head around this. Could anyone provide a helpful explanation? Which is more efficient and best practice?

Comment: They are **not** the same! Your second attempt is like this: `if($num_1 == TRUE)` Because `1 || 2` is  equals TRUE

Comment: The second one won't work, or not the way you expect.

Comment: `( 1 || 2 )` is always true

Comment: i tested this once but it didn't work as you would expect it. I only wanted to know the reason.

Comment: @MuhamadMuzahirKhodabucus Also see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php And a quote from there: `Warning
-1 is considered TRUE, like any other non-zero (whether negative or positive) number!` So since you have the OR statement in brackets, first it's `1 || 2` -> `TRUE` and then your expression is: `if($num_1 == TRUE)`

Comment: @Rizier Thank you for this clear explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the same. You can test it just by doing something like that:

```
$num_1 = 1;
var_dump($num_1 == ( 1 || 2 )); //true
var_dump($num_1 == 1 || $num_1 == 2); //true
$num_1 = 2;
var_dump($num_1 == ( 1 || 3 )); //true
var_dump($num_1 == 1 || $num_1 == 3); //false
```

The main reason for this is that when you are trying to do this:

```
if(1 || 2)
```

PHP will convert integers to booleans. So, your expresion become:

```
if(true||true) //what is actually true
```